# Exception Handling in C++ by throwing a string

Tags: c++

My program is following : (on linux)

```
// Ex. 2 of Exception Handling
// Here divn() raises the exception but main() will be the exception handler

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int divn(int n, int d)
{
    if(d == 0)
        throw "Division by ZERO not possible ";

    return n/d;
}

main()
{
    int numer, denom;
    cout << "Enter the numerator and denominator : ";
    cin >> numer >> denom;
    try
    {
        cout << numer << " / " << denom << " = " << divn(numer,denom) << endl;
    }
    catch(char *msg)
    {
        cout << msg;
    }
    cout << "\nEnd of main() \n ";
}
```

/*it should throw the exception and provide the given error message when we put denominator as 0. the output I get when i enter the denom as 0 is as follows :

> administrator@ubuntu:~/FYMCA/CPP_class$ g++ prog110.cpp
>   administrator@ubuntu:~/FYMCA/CPP_class$ ./a.out Enter the numerator
>   and denominator : 12 0 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'char const*' Aborted (core dumped)

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 11):

String literals have type `char const[]`, decaying to `char const*`. You should adjust your `catch` handler accordingly:

```
catch (char const* msg)
//          ^^^^^
{
    cout << msg;
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4zgAes%242).

Finally, here is a better way to rewrite your program, using exception classes from the C++ Standard Library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^ For std::logic_error

int divn(int n, int d)
{
    if(d == 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Division by ZERO not possible ");
        //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //    Throw by value
    }

    return n/d;
}

int main() // <== You should specify the return type of main()!
{
    // Rather use these than "using namespace std;"
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    int numer, denom;
    cout << "Enter the numerator and denominator : ";
    cin >> numer >> denom;

    try
    {
        cout << numer << " / " << denom << " = " << divn(numer,denom) << endl;
    }
    catch(std::logic_error const& err)
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //    Catch by reference
    {
        cout << err.what();
        //      ^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    cout << "\nEnd of main() \n ";
}
```

And the corresponding [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4zgAes%246) of course.

Answer (score 2):

The exception message kind of says it, you're catching the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

You should not throw exceptions in such a manner. A good practice is using standard exceptions in  stdexcept lib such as std::runtime_error or std::logic error or creating your own exception class based on the std::exception

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix is to add a statement towards the top as follows:

```
char * err = "Division by ZERO not possible";
```

Then, change your `throw` to `throw err;`

It has to do with how the compiler allocates storage for string literals.

Comment: The conversion to `char*` is illegal in C++11

Comment: Also, your should change your main() to int main() and include a return ( 0 ); at the end.

Comment: I did change my `main()`, and `return 0` is not necessary for `main()`.